# VIM: how to put result of a colon command into a variable?

Tags: vim

In VIM script, i want to check if VIM was started with command-line arguments or wthout. For this, i want to check a result of :args command that prints arguments. But how to put a result of :args inside an if() or a variable. Following wll not work:

```
let s:MyArgs = execute( "args" )
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to play with `:redir`. I have encapsulated this operation in a function [there](http://code.google.com/p/lh-vim/source/browse/vim-lib/trunk/autoload/lh/askvim.vim#31).

BTW, argc() should also answer your original need in a simpler way. (:h argc())